# How do I adjust Button size in Keyboard application? 

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a java application for my class. It's a telephone keypad. I'm almost finished with it. I just have to get the numbers to show I just don't have a clue of how to change the size of the number buttons. Everything I've tried so far has resulted in ERRORS when compiling.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TelephoneKeypad extends javax.swing.JFrame
{


    public TelephoneKeypad()
    {
        Panel pnlKeyPad = new Panel();
          GridLayout gridLayout1 = new GridLayout();
          Button btnZero = new Button();
          Button btnOne = new Button();
          Button btnTwo = new Button();
          Button btnThree = new Button();
        Button btnFour = new Button();
          Button btnFive = new Button();
          Button btnSix = new Button();
          Button btnSeven = new Button();
          Button btnEight = new Button();
          Button btnNine = new Button();
          Button btnStar = new Button();
          Button btnHash = new Button();

        TextField tfNumber = new TextField(15);
          Button btnDial = new Button();
          BorderLayout borderLayout1 = new BorderLayout();
          Panel pnlNumberEntry = new Panel();
          FlowLayout flowLayout1 = new FlowLayout();





            btnOne.setLabel("1");
            btnTwo.setLabel("2");
            btnThree.setLabel("3");
            btnFour.setLabel("4");
            btnFive.setLabel("5");
            btnSix.setLabel("6");
            btnSeven.setLabel("7");
            btnEight.setLabel("8");
            btnNine.setLabel("9");
            btnStar.setLabel("*");
            btnZero.setLabel("0");
            btnHash.setLabel("#");
            btnDial.setLabel("Dial");

            pnlNumberEntry.setLayout(flowLayout1);
            pnlKeyPad.setLayout(gridLayout1);
            this.setLayout(borderLayout1);
            this.add(pnlNumberEntry, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            pnlNumberEntry.add(tfNumber, null);
            pnlNumberEntry.add(btnDial, null);
            this.add(pnlKeyPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnOne, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnTwo, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnThree, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnFour, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnFive, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnSix, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnSeven, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnEight, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnNine, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnStar, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnZero, null);
            pnlKeyPad.add(btnHash, null);
        }

            public static void main(String args[])
                {
                TelephoneKeypad kpad = new TelephoneKeypad();
                kpad.setBounds(500, 500, 500, 500);
                kpad.setVisible(true);
    }
 }
```

Comment: See also [L&F size variants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899935/java-swing-low-profile-button-height/2900157#2900157).

Comment: See aslo [How to Use Actions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Comment: Your question is tagged with a Swing tag and you are using a JFrame, yet all your other components are AWT component. Don't mix AWT components in a Swing application. Make sure the components you use start with "J".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You instantiated `GridLayout` without any parameters. If you change it to

```
GridLayout gridLayout1 = new GridLayout(4,3);
```

You'll get much better view.

As a side note, if you use a layout object once, you can simply do

```
pnlKeyPad.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));
```

instead of

```
GridLayout gridLayout1 = new GridLayout(4,3);
pnlKeyPad.setLayout(gridLayout1);
```

(relevant for all of your layouts...)

Answer (score 5):

I have a couple of recommendations:

- set the GridLayout constants when calling its constructor.  e.g., `GridLayout gridLayout1 = new GridLayout(0, 3);`
- Don't set the bounds of your GUI but let the GUI's layout managers do this for you based on its preferred size.
- Don't forget to call pack() on the JFrame after adding all components
- I usually call `setLocationRelativeTo(null);` after calling `pack();` and before calling `setVisible(true);`
- Don't forget to call `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` in your class's (JFrame) constructor.
- One way to set the button's size is to set the Font of the button to be larger.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TPad extends JPanel {
   public static final String[][] BTN_TEXTS = {
      {"1", "2", "3"},
      {"4", "5", "6"},
      {"7", "8", "9"},
      {"*", "0", "#"}
   };
   private static final int GAP = 5;
   private static final int FONT_POINTS = 36;
   private static final Font BTN_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, FONT_POINTS);

   public TPad() {
      int rows = BTN_TEXTS.length;
      int cols = BTN_TEXTS[0].length;
      setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols, GAP, GAP));
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
      for (int row = 0; row < BTN_TEXTS.length; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < BTN_TEXTS[row].length; col++) {
            JButton btn = new JButton(BTN_TEXTS[row][col]);
            btn.setFont(BTN_FONT);
            add(btn);
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TPad");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new TPad());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: @Boro: thanks. Methinks you're going to run out of votes today just like I'm about to do (I Have only 4 votes left).

Comment: yea probably I will. Someone has to judge all these answers, right? :) Plus there is always another day with new votes :) All best to you.

Answer (score 4):

Refer [How to Use GridLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Also refer the constructors for [GridLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html)

---

Also try not to add a heavyweight component (`java.awt.Button`) on a lightweight component(`javax.swing.JFrame`).

> Because Awt uses native GUI widgets,
>   your OS knows about them and handles
>   putting them in front of each other,
>   etc. Whereas with Swing your widgets
>   are just meaningless pixels within a
>   window; Swing handles deciding how
>   your widgets lay out and stack. Mixing
>   the two is highly unsupported and can
>   lead to ridiculous results, such as
>   native buttons that obscure everything
>   else in the dialog box in which they
>   reside because everything else was
>   created with Swing.
>   - [What is the difference between swing and AWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408820/what-is-the-difference-between-swing-and-awt/408830#408830)

Comment: +1 well spot mixing of heavy and light weight components. It is recommended to never mix these two types of objects. If you must here is a great [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/) explaining what to expect.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I adjust Button size in Keyboard application?

See my answer to [Removing the three dots “…” from a JButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808195/removing-the-three-dots-from-a-jbutton/5809789#5809789) re adjusting the font size using run-time parameters.